# JSON conditional output

Tags: java, json, rest, api, swagger

I am new to REST API, so I am not sure whether I have phrased the question correctly.

I have a Java class with two attributes.

```
class TestClass {

    private double rate;
    private double quantity;

    @ApiModelProperty
    getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    @ApiModelProperty
    getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
}
```

I have an API, which when i call, fetches data from an SQL table and returns a JSON object as shown(I have used examples):

```
{
    rate = 5;
    quantity = 10;
}
```

I want to modify the output so that only either rate or quantity would be displayed depending on the condition. How do i do it?

Comment: Always start Class names with Capital letters.

Comment: yeah, you're right there..thanks

Comment: Try using `Double` over `double` and set the value to null based on condition

Comment: Yes, I'll try to use Double..thank you Arvind

Answer (score 0):

You can have two API methods that each returns different object

```
class TestClassRate {

    private double rate;

    @ApiModelProperty
    getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

}

class TestClassQuantity {

    private double quantity;

    @ApiModelProperty
    getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would there be any way to do it without using two different objects?

Comment: Only way I can think of is as @Arvind said. Using Double instead of double and setting one of the property to null.

Comment: Yeah, i think that would be the best here...thank you

Answer (score 0):

what is the condition? if you want to show only not null field, you have to make the correct configuration of your json provider.

For example, if you're using Jackson :

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
```